# Kubernetes-Pod : Access issues

Tags: kubernetes

Getting following error while accessing the pod...

> "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348:
>   starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat
>   /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown command terminated with
>   exit code 126"

Tried with /bin/sh & /bin/bash
Terminated the node on which this pod  is running and bring up the new node, but the result is same.
Also tried deleting the pod, but new pod also behaves in the similar way.

Comment: you try to execute `/bin/bash` in an image that does not have that file or directory.

Comment: What is the name of the image you're using ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the container you're trying to access doesn't have the `/bin/bash` executable.

If you really want to execute a shell in the container, you have to use a container image that includes a shell (e.g. `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`).